# Creating a multindex'd column DataFrame (expanded explanation)

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a dataframe that should have two levels of columns:  upper level will be an arbitrary number of measurements, and then the second level will have an 'avg' and 'sd' sub-column for each of the measurements.

I'd like to assemble the dataframe by adding column sets (measurement + avg&sd subcolumns) one-by-one, but I can't figure out how to do add new multilevel columns in pandas incrementally.  *How can I do this?*

So as an alternative, I assemble the dataFrame all at once, and then fill in the values using dataframe.ix.

But my code for doing this assemble-all-at-once is horrific, because I have an arbitrary number of measurements (upper level) and statistical_vales (lower level) on a given run of the function.  Here's a horrible hacked version given 4 upper levels and 2 lower levels on the columns.  How could I replace this disgusting code?

```
hackColumnsUpperAttributes=['CHG_NET_1D','CHG_NET_1D','VOLUME','VOLUME','OPEN_INT','OPEN_INT','d_OI','d_OI']
hackColumnsLowerStats=["avg","sd","avg","sd","avg","sd","avg","sd"]

stats=pd.DataFrame(index=securities, columns = [hackColumnsUpperAttributes, hackColumnsLowerStats])
```

Also wondering what is better practice -- to build the dataframe incrementall (first approach) or to built it all when i construct the dataframe and then fill in the individual cells.

EDIT:  As requested, here's an example dataframe

[image: Example data frame as requested]

My programmatic issue is that I will have an arbitrary number of the top level columns (CHG_NET_1D, VOLUME, OPEN_INT, D_OI, etc. etc. etc.)  I need to give each of those columns sub columns of "avg" and "sd".

problems:
(1) I cannot figure out how to incrementally add more columns/sub-columns to dataframe
(2) If I want to assemble the whole dataframe at once (not incrementally add columns) then I don't know a nice way to create arbitrary number of multilevel columns. I end up doing something gross like the hackColumns example above.

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you show a desired dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I have added that extra info.

Comment: are you still working on this, or did you move on? Fell free to ask follow-ups if you got stranded, otherwise you can close it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your row indices are consistent, you can add incrementally by `pd.concat`.

To the extent that I understand your issue, here's one approach--depending on what your generating process is, it may or may not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

outer_1 =['open','close','vol',]
outer_2 =['high','low']
inner = ['sd','mean']
tickers=['AAPL','MSFT','NTES','GOOG']
```

Here, we define `outer_1` and `outer_2` as known outer levels, assuming they are known (if arbitrary). For these, we want the stats in `inner`. (Fill in the actual calculation logic).

```
measure1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,6),index=tickers,columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([outer_1,inner], names=['grp', 'detail']))
```

First frame is then

```
measure1.head()

grp         open               close                 vol          
detail        sd      mean        sd      mean        sd      mean
AAPL    1.809306 -0.218046 -0.847634 -0.652089 -1.089633 -0.784762
MSFT   -0.370508 -1.405567  0.015618  0.902277 -0.907756  1.519284
NTES    0.510792  1.030581 -0.657835  0.854525 -1.091934  0.890248
GOOG    0.171839  0.553251 -1.175595 -0.895070  0.597228 -0.948348
```

and, let's say you want to expand this frame with another number of summary stats (for the same row indices, but different outer column indices):

```
measure2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4),index=tickers,columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([outer_2,inner], names=['grp', 'detail']))
measure2.head()


grp         high                 low          
detail        sd      mean        sd      mean
AAPL    0.679143 -0.302045 -0.329448  0.731871
MSFT    0.335058  0.316156  0.469268 -1.535572
NTES    0.756789  0.612469 -1.016683 -0.244080
GOOG   -0.039307 -0.134497  0.333860  1.431367
```

Then, you can combine, merging on row indices (`axis=1`).

```
pd.concat([measure1,measure2],axis=1)

grp         open               close                 vol                high                 low          
detail        sd      mean        sd      mean        sd      mean        sd      mean        sd      mean
AAPL    1.809306 -0.218046 -0.847634 -0.652089 -1.089633 -0.784762  0.679143 -0.302045 -0.329448  0.731871
MSFT   -0.370508 -1.405567  0.015618  0.902277 -0.907756  1.519284  0.335058  0.316156  0.469268 -1.535572
NTES    0.510792  1.030581 -0.657835  0.854525 -1.091934  0.890248  0.756789  0.612469 -1.016683 -0.244080
GOOG    0.171839  0.553251 -1.175595 -0.895070  0.597228 -0.948348 -0.039307 -0.134497  0.333860  1.431367
```

Comment: Did this example of assembling the dataframe in steps work for you?